# How many AVD can be running at once?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I would like to start few AVD. I have created images in Android Studio.

Two AVD launch. Third and more freezes during launch (black screen) when I try to start it.

Is there some kind of limit to it? How does it work for you? Is there any way to launch more of them?

Comment: The limit is on your computer hardware. They all consume lots of memory and CPU/GPU processing. If you could have a super-multi-core-multi-processor super computer you could probably run lots of them at once. But for your traditional laptop/destop machine, stick to just 1 is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are overloading the JVM with new hardcore-consuming processes.
An **AVD virtual device consumes a lot of resources** (both Memory and CPU) and if you are spawning several, you can clear notice that the workload will be fairly increased.

Android Studio alone consumes in average 1.5-2.0 GB of memory. Additionally JAVA requires itself about 1.0 GB of memory. If you sum up about 512MB of Ram for each AVD, you will exaust your machine.

[Take a look at this AVD Mangement reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html)